# Trying to pass htaccess and login into redmine api

Tags: php, .htaccess, curl, redmine, redmine-api

I want to connect to the Redmine API. The page is protected by a `.htaccess` file.
As long as the user credentials (name + password) are the same for `.htaccess` and Redmine, there aren't any problems.

Well... Two of my teammates are using different credentials (their error code: `401, not authorized`) and they just don't want to change them.

Actually, I think this is because they don't pass `.htaccess` (with their credentials) or they pass `.htaccess` but aren't able to use Redmine with their data.

I was searching for hours (well, at least since 12:30 o'clock) but couldn't resolve this problem. I just can't figure out how to pass the `.htaccess` and API credentials correctly.

My Code:

```
$sURL = 'https://myserver/redmine/';
$sAction = 'projects.json';
$sApiUser = 'user_name';
$sApiPass = 'user_pass';
$sHtAccUser = 'htacc_user';
$sHtAccPass = 'htacc_pass';
#$sURL = sprintf('https://%s:%s@myserver/redmine/',$sUser,$sPass);

$aOptions   = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_USERPWD         => $sUser.':'.$sPass,
    CURLOPT_PORT            => 443,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT  => 4,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT         => 6,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => FALSE,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => FALSE,
    CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH        => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
    CURLOPT_HEADER          => FALSE,
    #CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array('Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode($sHtAccUser.':'.$sHtAccPass)),
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_URL             => $sURL.$sAction.$sGetParamQuery);

$ch = curl_init();
if($ch === false)
{
    die('Failed to create curl object');
}           
curl_setopt_array($ch,$aOptions);
$mResult = curl_exec($ch);
$aCurlInfo = curl_getinfo($ch);     
$iHTTPStatus = (int) $aCurlInfo['http_code'];
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: I think both of your methods are basically setting HTTPAuth just by two different ways thus overriding each other. (Setting in the url also is ignored by many browsers/webservers for security reasons). Are you sure Redmine is ALSO using htaccess in addition to ANOTHER htaccess on your webserver? (Im no redmine expert, sadly)

Comment: Hi ToBe,
yes, I already figured out that both methods do the same. 
Actually I just think, that I have to access the htaccess rule from server + redmine API. I'm not sure about it.

I just can't figure out, why I can access my tool (I use the same credentials for htaccess + redmine api), while my mates (which use different credentials for htaccess and redmine) can't access.

Answer (score 0):

So, after I had a conversation with someone who is more experienced, I could solve the problem "myself".

Actually, htaccess and redmine use the same authentication method (HTTP Basic authentication), which can't used twice. For this reason, I have to use the individual API key (which you can found at /my/account, on your own redmine).

As long as both credentials (htaccess + redmine) are the same, you don't need the API key.
If the credentials are different... well, you have to login into redmine, get your API key and use it. Maybe not a comfortable way but actually the way to go.